# Text color change when button is disabled in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, uwp

i am working in UWP aplication. i have button which textcolor changes to black when it is disabled. i m trying to change it white using trigger like this

```
 <Button x:Name="btnEnter" Grid.Column="2" Text="Enter" BackgroundColor="#092B73" TextColor="White" Clicked="btnEnter_Clicked" >
        <Button.Triggers>
          <Trigger TargetType="Button"
               Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger TargetType="Button"
               Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
          </Trigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

but it is not working.please help to find where m wrong

UPDATE

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="StockDispatchApp.Views.TestDisableButton">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
 <StackLayout >
<Button x:Name="btn1" Text="Button1"  Clicked="btn1_clicked"></Button>
<Button x:Name="btn2" Text="Button2" BackgroundColor="Green"   TextColor="White"></Button>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In btn1 clicked i just disabled btn2 to check it

Comment: You are setting it to `White` in every case.

Comment: but i want white textcolor in both case.

Comment: when it disable its color gets changed black.that i dont want

Comment: Use custom renderers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49193488/1039935

Answer (score 1):

Copy / paste the default Button style that is listed on MSDN ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx ) and tweak it to your liking.

In your case, look for the Disabled storyboard and change the

`<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">`

To a color you like or a theme resource...

Comment: "it throws Can't resolve TemplateProperty on Button" exception

Comment: Ow, I see you have used colours! The properties are brushes, so change that first!!

Comment: Dude... for example this in your code :                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames> You put WHITE in a BorderBRUSH that won't work